# Add Nodes to existing OpenMPI cluster in aws cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, openmpi

Can I add more nodes to openMPI environment after it is created?  This is related to the openMPI running in cloud instances.  Suppose I have start a few cloud instances and setup OpenMPI, I can then submit jobs to it.  Suppose the job queue are long and I want to request more cloud instances, can I add it to the existing openMPI environment or I have to create a new MPI cluster with those newly added instances?

Update: I am wondering if the following strategy for adding more nodes without interrupt the currently running job works.
1. Install Torque as job scheduler and configure the existing AWS instances.  Use qsub to submit mpi jobs which takes all existing nodes.
2. Request more instance in amazon cloud.  Add nodes to torque using qmgr.
3. qsub another mpi job and it should run on the newly added nodes?

Will it work?  What configuration I have to run for openmpi and torque?  My AWS image will have openmpi and torque installed. I suppose I need to copy key files to those new nodes? Do I have to update hostfiles for openmpi or it is now managed by torque?

Comment: Did you actually mean to ask if you could add more processes to an already running MPI job? Open MPI is not a resource manager and it can use any number of nodes as provided in the hostfile configuration.

Comment: No, I know you can't add more processes to an already running MPI job.  I only want to request more instances to run a new job while the existing instances is occupied by old job.

Comment: I suppose I can request more instance and then create a hostfile1 and mpirun with the new hostfile1.  Is there job scheduler that support this or I have to write my own job scheduler?  Alternatively, can I simply update the existing hostfile, and the new jobs started by mpirun will grab the new unused nodes while the old jobs were running on the old nodes?

Comment: Open MPI is a message passing library and not a distributed resource manager. Besides, `mpiexec` takes the hostfile as a parameter and you can provide each instance of `mpiexec` with a separate hostfile.